# SAP ADT 'installing software' has encountered a problem - Eclipse IDE

Tags: 20.04, eclipse, adt

When installing 'new software' in Eclipse IDE (*Help* → *Install New Software...*) and following exactly the steps as described [here](https://medium.com/@acarahmet/installation-abap-development-tool-adt-on-eclipse-a150585b8532), I encounter this problem (at steps 8 - 9):

[image: Eclipse error]

Here is the full error output:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=_home_mohammad_eclipse_java-2020-12_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.adt.abap.prog.rap.doc.dev_3.14.100.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.adt.abapdev.guide.doc.user_3.14.100.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.adt.hana.guide.doc.user_3.14.100.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.docu.bpc4hana.help_1.23.0.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.docu.bpc4hana2.help_1.23.0.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.docu.bw.help_1.23.0.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.docu.bw4hana2.help_1.23.0.jar.
Connection reset
Unable to read repository at https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2020-12/plugins/com.sap.mts.processintegration.guide.doc.user_1.124.0.jar.
Connection reset
```

I had exactly the same issue on Windows, and It was because Eclipse was installed in `Windows drive/Program Files`. So I just needed to provide **admin permission** or **move eclipse out** of `Program Files`.

But on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa), I don't know what to do.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try starting Eclipse with these following arguments :

```
-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Is this supposed to solve OP's problem? If yes, how would it do that? Please provide more info.